# Addax in the Land of Israel

Tags: zoology, ecology, biogeography

The Addax (*Addax nasomaculatus*) is critically endangered species of a desert anetelope with impressive long horns. Today there are small populations in the Sahara desert and the Arabian desert (Saudi Arabia). The addax is mentioned in the bible ("Dishon"), though the identification is not uninomous. Today in Israel there are breeding centers for the addax, one in Hai-Bar Yotvata (near Eilat, the rift valley, bay of the Red Sea) and the other in the Zoological Center at Ramat Gan ("The Safari"), but as far as I know, there are no plans to release addax in the wild in Israel (although I think it can survive and flourish there).

The question is: was the addax native to the Land of Israel (before it was eradicated from it by overhunting)? Do the conservation organizations support reintroduce it to the wild in Israel (in addition to the Sahara and the Arabian desert) addax herds from the breeding centers? The reintroduction of Oryx to the wild in Israel was pretty successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Yossef Braslevi, "HaYadata Et HaHaretz - Yam HaMelach Saviv Saviv" ("And you shall know the land - The Dead Sea and its Surroundings", 1956, Vol. C, page 199 -- the answer is **positive**. There were native addaxes in the Land of Israel.